# How to save all test report to separate file in Junit

Tags: maven, junit

I am writing Junit test cases for my project for that, i added junit dependencies to my pom.xml

and by giving the below command i am able to run the test cases

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests = false
```

All tests are runnig successfully.

But, I want to save the test report to separate file with including AssertionErrors also

How can i save the test report into another file. Can any one please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [maven-surefire-report-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/usage.html).

Basic configuration example:

```
<plugins
   ...
   <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.17</version>
   </plugin>
</plugins>
```

To create a test-report in a separate file, you have to execute:

```
mvn surefire-report:report -DouputFile=YourFileName.html
```

If you don't specify a different output directory, by default the report will be generated in `target/site` folder

Hope it helps